# Is there any REST API for Docker HUB repository info and Dockerfile update?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I build an autobuild process for a lot [dockerfiles](https://github.com/wenerme/dockerfiles) runs on [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/wenerme/dockerfiles).

Now I can update images, but can I also update repo info or dockerfile ?

I found [Docker Hub API](https://docs.docker.com/v1.4/reference/api/docker-io_api/), but no info update, no dockerfile update.

Comment: you are trying to update the `Dockerfiles` or the `images`? if are just the images you could use just do a `docker push` in the end of your build.
info: https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_six/

Comment: I want to update the Dockerfile and Repo Info for [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/wener/base/) via REST API.This Repo has no Description and Dockerfile, and I don't want to manually add this.

Comment: the "easy" way would be change to use the docker hub's automated build to create the images... the `Dockerfiles` would be automatically updated at the build because I think there is no other way to update it. You can try to use the endpoint `https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/<user>/<image>/` to try to update, I would add the docs for this url, but I did not find any

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a bit late, but if you're trying to set/update the description and short description of a container repo on Docker Hub after having pushed to it maybe try [`docker-pushrm`](https://github.com/christian-korneck/docker-pushrm), a CLI plugin for Docker. It stands for *Docker Push Readme* and updates the info of the Docker Hub repo from the *README* file in the current directory.

```
$ ls
README.md
docker pushrm --short "some short description" myuser/myrepo
```

For CI it's also available as a [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/chko/docker-pushrm) and a [github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/update-container-description-action).